# Why is onclick for the first button in a form triggered when I hit ENTER key (and no keyCode in event)?

Tags: javascript, html

Why is onclick for the first button in a form triggered when I hit ENTER key? I am trying to figure out why onclick was triggered by the ENTER key, and then have the function go ahead if it was an actual mouse/tap button click, or have the function ignore the key press if it was the ENTER key.

I tried checking the event.keyCode (passed into javascript function), but it is undefined.

In fact the only property that seems to be set is event.isTrusted but no other properties exist.

EDIT: Created new demo code to better explain the issue I am having...

Here is js fiddle with the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Ld142qx3/24/

When you put the cursor in the Quantity 2 input box (the second box) and you click enter, it fires the onclick event for the first LESS button in front of the Quantity 1 input box.

There is no keyCode property passed in with event to identify whether onclick was actually triggered by clicking with a mouse or triggered by ENTER key.

My original test code HTML is:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  Quantity 1: <button id="b1-less" onclick="return b1Less(this.id, event);">less</button>
  <input type="text" id="q1" value="10" size="10">
  <button id="b1-more" onclick="return b1More(this.id, event);">more</button>
  <br>
  Quantity 2: <button id="b2-less" onclick="return b2Less(this.id, event);">less</button>
  <input type="text" id="q2" value="5" size="10">
  <button id="b2-more" onclick="return b2More(this.id, event);">more</button>
</form>
```

And my original javascript to go with it is:

```
function b1Less(_id, _event) {
  alert(_event.keyCode);
  _val = parseInt(document.getElementById('q1').value);
  _val = _val - 1;
  document.getElementById('q1').value = _val;
  return false;
}
function b1More(_id, _event) {
  _val = parseInt(document.getElementById('q1').value);
  _val = _val + 1;
  document.getElementById('q1').value = _val;
  return false;
}

function b2Less(_id, _event) {
  _val = parseInt(document.getElementById('q2').value);
  _val = _val - 1;
  document.getElementById('q2').value = _val;
  return false;
}
function b2More(_id, _event) {
  _val = parseInt(document.getElementById('q2').value);
  _val = _val + 1;
  document.getElementById('q2').value = _val;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect `keyCode` to be defined on a `click` event? try adding `onkeyup="doClickMeButton(event, this.id)"` to your `input` and you will see keyCode values...

Comment: @jsherk I have uploaded the answer you can check, just curious why the click me button is present what functionality are you trying to achieve

Comment: @Adityatoke I just re-created new demo code that better shows the problem I am having. I removed the CLICK ME button.

Comment: @Nick The ENTER key causes onclick to fire but there is no keyCode property to determine whether it was fired by mouse click or ENTER key. I have created new demo code to better show the issue.

Comment: Feels like a dirty hack but it is default behavior in browsers... Shocking truly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that the type of a button inside a form defaults to a `"submit"` button (see the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)), and when a form is implicitly submitted (which happens when you press `ENTER` in an input field, the first `"submit"` button in the form also has its `onclick` event handler triggered (see the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#implicit-submission)). Changing your buttons to have `type="button"` resolves the issue:

```js
function b1Less(_id, _event) {
  _val = parseInt(document.getElementById('q1').value);
  _val = _val - 1;
  document.getElementById('q1').value = _val;
  return false;
}

function b1More(_id, _event) {
  _val = parseInt(document.getElementById('q1').value);
  _val = _val + 1;
  document.getElementById('q1').value = _val;
  return false;
}

function b2Less(_id, _event) {
  _val = parseInt(document.getElementById('q2').value);
  _val = _val - 1;
  document.getElementById('q2').value = _val;
  return false;
}

function b2More(_id, _event) {
  _val = parseInt(document.getElementById('q2').value);
  _val = _val + 1;
  document.getElementById('q2').value = _val;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  Quantity 1: <button type="button" id="b1-less" onclick="return b1Less(this.id, event);">less</button>
  <input type="text" id="q1" value="10" size="10">
  <button type="button" id="b1-more" onclick="return b1More(this.id, event);">more</button>
  <br> Quantity 2: <button type="button" id="b2-less" onclick="return b2Less(this.id, event);">less</button>
  <input type="text" id="q2" value="5" size="10">
  <button type="button" id="b2-more" onclick="return b2More(this.id, event);">more</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, Nick!
It's frustrating when the default behavior of a button inside a form causes unexpected bugs in the program.

The first button is a delete button which is nested a lot. When I press enter, something is deleted. WTF!
It's worked when I change the type to 'button'. Or JUST change the button to div.

What I want to say is, ALWAYS using div to implement custom component if you can.
What a amazing DEFAULT behavior!

Comment: @binglongli yeah, I think this is a result of people trying to make other people's lives easier without thinking through *all* the possible consequences. I'm glad this helped.

Answer (score 0):

As checked `doClickMeButton` function event is a mouse event and mouse event doesn't have keyboard binding details.
     
     You can bind a keyboard-based events on an `input` tag.
     I have mentioned the code below which behaves the same as you wanted.

```js
function doClickMeButton() {
  alert("I am called");
}

function doMoreLess(_id) {
  alert("clicked on " + _id);
  return false;
}

function myFunction(event) {
  var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if (x === 13) {
    console.log(event.which, "which"), console.log(event.keyCode, "keycode");
    doClickMeButton();
  }
}
```

```html
 <form>
 
         // first thing I dont know why you need this button
        <button id="my-button"
       
        onclick="">CLICK ME</button>
      
        <br>
        Enter something in the input textbox below, and hit the ENTER key and notice that:<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;(1) keyCode is undefined, and<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;(2) ENTER fires the onclick action of the first element with an onclick in it.
        <br>
      
        <button id="less" onclick="return doMoreLess(this.id);">
        less
        </button>
        <input type="text" size="10"  onkeypress="myFunction(event)">
        <button id="more" onclick="return doMoreLess(this.id);">
        more
        </button>
      </form>
```